# play framework 2.0 evolutions plugin won't run on startup

Tags: playframework-2.0

when i run my play framework 2.0 scala app via 'play run', i get sql errors, because the sql evolutions (aka migrations) were never run. i start from a brand new database.

i know the evolutions plugin is running because i can see an empty play_evolutions table in my database.

what can cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can happen under two circumstances:

1. the evolution file has a sql syntax error, causing the evolution to fail. (this wasn't my problem but someone on the mailing list said this happened to them.)
2. the 1.sql file is under the incorrect dir structure "evolutions.default/1.sql" instead of "evolutions/default/1.sql". unfortunately intellij cannot tell the difference and renders both situations identically in the project explorer.

further reading:

- [how to apply evolutions in production](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/play-framework/manual%2420evolution/play-framework/0DWLfJMDq4w/JZKlA9zugQYJ)
- [mailing list thread about evolutions not running at start](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/play-framework/manual%2420evolution/play-framework/yoA7eRmLsUc/OFxQ-rym5G0J)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to set your evolutions to run automatically when you start Play. You can do this by adding

```
applyEvolutions.default=true
```

to your application.conf file. With this set to true, evolutions will be applied every time you start up your app.